# Android App works on phone in debug mode but not when downloaded from Play Store due to missing MainActivity

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-activity

I have a Flutter app that works fine in debug mode on the phone but crashes on startup in release mode due to not able to find MainActivity. Can anyone see where my configuration is incorrect?

The history of this project is that I am attempting to upgrade an existing app to meet Google API requirements.  It took some time to get the upload key working properly, which I believe was caused by the package name for the new project being incorrectly specified as com.simplegradebook.simplegradebook.  The original app used just com.simplegradebook.

When I altered the package name the upload key started working.  However, I think that alteration caused this new issue.  Hoping to fix this without recreating the project yet again.

All suggestions welcome.

Error:

```
    2023-11-09 11:12:30.074 30254-30254 AndroidRuntime          pid-30254                            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.simplegradebook, PID: 30254
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.simplegradebook/com.simplegradebook.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.simplegradebook.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.fr.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.fr.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4051)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.simplegradebook.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.fr.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.fr.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/~~bPyVuggYllXzkUk6SFFvxQ==/com.simplegradebook-yiUEzfIlNLukOOb5TYpHuQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
```

Unmerged Android Release Manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="simplegradebook"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Merged Android Release Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.simplegradebook"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="4.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />

    <application
        android:name="com.simplegradebook.simplegradebook"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="simplegradebook" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.simplegradebook.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

            <!--
                 Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Merged Android Debug Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.simplegradebook"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="4.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <!--
         The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="android.app.Application"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="simplegradebook" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.simplegradebook.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

            <!--
                 Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
    
    plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.simplegradebook"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.simplegradebook"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationName: "simplegradebook"]
            println(signingConfigs.release.keyAlias)
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
    name: simplegradebook
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 4.0.0+10

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.6
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0 #For asking permission to load the pdf
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^5.0.6595
  intl: ^0.17.0
  visibility_detector: ^0.2.2

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Picture of the file structure for the MainActivity package:

https://imgur.com/a/CC9t0n6

Comment: Possibly a R8 or proguard error renaming the class.

Comment: Some additional information:  when I build the apk and analyze it, the class com.simplegradebook.Mainactivity is there in the classes.dex file.  Is this simply a case of ignoring certain warnings/errors?

Comment: This appears to be related to an issue with two-section package names.   My original app was built with a two-section package name com.simplegradebook.  However, after upgrading to Giraffe, it appears that two-section package names are no longer supported.  I tried to upload a package using com.simplegradebook.simplegradebook, but the Play Console rejected it and said it had to be com.simplegradebook.  So, the question now is, is it even possible to create a two-section package name in Android Studio and Kotlin? Maybe I will try again with Java...

Comment: Java vs kotlin won't effect something like that which is a playstore policy.

Comment: So, I created a project called just simplegradebook, with a package name com.simplegradebook.simplegradebook.  Then I altered the AndroidManifest and fixed up build.gradle to use com.simplegradebook, changed the directory structure at android/app/src/main to match com.simplegradebook, invalidated caches, ran Make in the Android directory, recreated the bundle and it started working.  Odd, because I had done this same procedure before.  In any case, it is fixed.